# What are the pros and cons of personalized medicine?

Tags: health-informatics

I've been hearing a lot about this term lately, and was wondering what exactly it is, and whether it really is the future of the medicine industry. What are the advantages and benefits, along with disadvantages of such a system, if it is feasible on a large scale?

Comment: Significantly less side-effects?

Comment: I suspect it's mainly a meaningless buzz-word.

Comment: This is not a constructive question for the current scope of the site. It was asked long before the current scope was defined and began to be enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Pros are

- better treatment (e.g., IL-5 inhibitor will not help if you do not have a subtype of asthma that is eosinofilic) (by knowing your type the therapy will be more targeted at your subtype of disease)

Cons are

- more complex diagnostic workup to arrive at personalized care (e.g., must get sequencing results to recommend best action for Lynch syndrome)